# Как изменить ключ сессии в Django?

Tags: python, django

Мне надо сделать так, чтобы пользователь получал авторизационную куку с именем `sessionid`.

По исходникам нашел значение `SESSION_KEY` с другим значением. Если задать свое значение `SESSION_KEY` в `settings.py` или где-нибудь еще, то ничего не изменится.

Как можно наиболее простым способом реализовать это ? В проекте используется `Django 1.6` и `python 2.7`.

Comment: `sessionid` - это же и так значение по умолчанию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите изменить имя cookie для сессии, то вам надо поменять параметр

```
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME
```

Остальные параметры влияющие на сессию вы можете посмотреть в документации [Настройка сессии](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#sessions)